# Execute a HQL request

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I tried to execute the following request in HQL:

```
session1.createQuery("select p from Projet p inner join p.domaine d where p.site = :site")
                            .setString("site", selected)
                            .list();
```

But in the result i'm getting the id of the table domaine, not the value of the column that i want to display which is a String.
PS/I have a many to one relation between domaine and pojet.
Have i forget to add sometnig

Projet.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25 avr. 2015 06:50:10 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bean.Projet" table="PROJET">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="libelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LIBELLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="site" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SITE" />
        </property>
        <property name="finalite" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FINALITE" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_actuelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_ACTUELLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_debut" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_DEBUT" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_previsionnelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_PREVISIONNELLE" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="domaine" class="bean.Domaine" fetch="join">
            <column name="IDDOMAINE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <set name="assignedActeurs" table="PROJET_ACTEUR" inverse="false"
            lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many class="bean.Acteur">
                <column name="IDACTEUR" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="assignedBénéficiaires" table="PROJET_BENEFICIAIRE"
            inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many class="bean.Bénéficiaire">
                <column name="IDBENEFICIAIRE" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>

        <many-to-one name="chefprojet" class="bean.Chefprojet"
            fetch="join">
            <column name="ID_CHEF" />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Domaine.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25 avr. 2015 06:50:10 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bean.Domaine" table="DOMAINE">
        <id name="idDomaine" type="int">
            <column name="IDDOMAINE" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="type_domaine" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TYPE_DOMAINE" />
        </property>
        <set name="assignedProjets" table="PROJET" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="IDDOMAINE" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="bean.Projet" />
        </set>
        <set name="assignedChantiers" table="CHANTIER" fetch="select"
            cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="IDDOMAINE" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="bean.Chantier" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

liste.jsp

```
<html>

<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="acceuil.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ajoutprojet.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" /></script>

</head>

<%
    List projects = (List) request.getAttribute("listProject");
    if (projects == null)
        projects = new ArrayList();
%>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/Captureocp.PNG"
                alt="" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="acceuil.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>

    <form method="post" action="liste">
        <p>
            <select name="sites">
                <option value="">-- Choisir --</option>
                <option value="Khouribga">Khouribga</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Casablanca</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Jorf Lasfar</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Benguerir</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Boucraa</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Youssoufia</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Laayoune</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Safi</option>

            </select><br />

        </p>
        <div class="centre">

            <input type="submit" value="Chercher" name="Chercher" />
        </div>


        <table border="1" cellpadding="3pt" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Liste des projets :</td>
            </tr>


            <c:forEach var="projet" items="${listProject}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.libelle}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.site}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.finalite}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.date_actuelle}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.date_debut}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.date_previsionnelle}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.domaine.idDomaine}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet.chefprojet.id_chef}" /></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

la Servlet:

```
public class listeControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);


        try {
            Session session1=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            String selected=request.getParameter("sites");
            session1.beginTransaction();
            List<Projet> list = 
                    session1.createQuery("select p.id, p.site,p.libelle,p.finalite,p.date_actuelle,p.date_debut,p.date_previsionnelle, d.type_domaine from Projet p inner join p.domaine d where p.site = :site")
                            .setString("site", selected)
                            .list();
            request.setAttribute("listProject", list);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("liste.jsp").forward(request, response);
            session1.close(); 

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the mapping of the relation between domaine and poject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to select all the columns from the `Project` table and only one column from the `Domaine` table, so you need to explicitly pass all those columns in the select query like this:

```
session1.createQuery("select p.id, p.libelle, p.site, p.finalite, p.date_actuelle, d.type_domaine from Projet p inner join p.domaine d where p.site = :site")
                        .setString("site", selected)
                        .list();
```

**EDIT:**

When you use this query you will not get a list of `Project`s but instead a list of `Object`s because you are merging columns from `Project` and `Domaine` so you should need to change your code like this:

**Servlet:**

```
List<Object> list = 
                session1.createQuery("select p.id, p.site,p.libelle,p.finalite,p.date_actuelle,p.date_debut,p.date_previsionnelle, d.type_domaine from Projet p inner join p.domaine d where p.site = :site")
                        .setString("site", selected)
                        .list();
```

**JSP:**

And in your jsp you get the results using `object[index]` where `index` is the attribute index in your select part of the query, here's what you need:

```
<c:forEach var="projet" items="${listProject}">
     <tr>
         <td><c:out value="${projet[2]}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${projet[1]}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${projet[3]}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${projet[4]}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${projet[5]}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${projet[6]}" /></td>
         <!-- you should include idDomaine and id_chef in your query to get them here -->
         <td><c:out value="${projet.domaine.idDomaine}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${projet.chefprojet.id_chef}" /></td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I tried this code but i'm getting these errors: > GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "libelle"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:151)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:64)

Comment: I think while you are fetching the results you are using `Integer.parseInt()` with a String value in `libelle`, it is a String?? isn't it?

Comment: Please post the part of your code where you are fetching the results, so I can help.

Comment: @salma Ok I'm Editing my answer.

Comment: Shoud i replace the numbers in index with the corresponding columns?

Comment: Yes and remember that index starts from `0`, `id-->0`, `site-->1`, `libelle-->2` and so on.

Comment: I'm getting the same error but now with: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "domaine"

Comment: Have you passed the Domaine id like this `d.type_domaine, d.idDomaine` in the query and used `<td><c:out value="${projet[7]}" /></td>` to get the id Domaine in your jsp???

Comment: i'm going to try that now, i forget to add it

Comment: but how can i add idDomaine in the query, cauz i don't need it?

Comment: So what are you using `<td><c:out value="${projet.domaine.idDomaine}" /></td>` if you don't need it?

Comment: i need one column from table Domaine. So i think i should place <td><c:out value="${projet.domaine.type_domaine}" /></td>; the column which i want to display. am i right?

Comment: Yes but it should be `<td><c:out value="${projet[index in the query]}" /></td>`.

Comment: I'm verry sorry i disturb you... [index in the query] you mean 'type_domaine' or i should replace it by number '7' which is the emplacement of type_domaine in the query?

Comment: Here is the query {session1.createQuery("select p.id, p.site,p.libelle,p.finalite,p.date_actuelle,p.date_debut,p.date_previsionnelle, d.type_domaine from Projet p inner join p.domaine d where p.site = :site")
                .setString("site", selected)
                .list();}

Comment: @chsk i think i was having a problem with eclipse. I switch it off, and switch it on again and the query works! i have now the result exactly like i need it. Thank u so much chsk, you save me!

Comment: @salma Yes I meant `7`, but anyway glad it helps and  you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The query should look like this:

```
select p.id, p.libelle, ...(all the columns you need), d.type_domaine from Projet p inner join p.domaine d where p.site = :site
```

where the desiderColumn is the name of the single column you want to select

Comment: From the first table wich is Projet, i want to select all the columns but from the second i want to display just one column. How can i do it? I tried the following request: select p from Projet p inner join p.domaine.desiderColumn d where p.site = :site But it is not working.